# Spring Data JPA make many selects by id when save

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this models:

DataModel:

```java
@Table(name = "data_model")
public class DataModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "model_id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "dataModel", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<OutputField> outputFields;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "dataModel", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<IncrementField> incrementFields;

}
```

OutputField:

```java
@Table(name = "data_model_output_field")
public class OutputField {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "output_field_id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "model_id")
    private DataModel dataModel;

}
```

IncrementField:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_model_increment_field")
public class IncrementField {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "increment_field_id")
    private Integer id;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "model_id")
    private DataModel dataModel;
}
```

I have service method:

```java
@Transactional
public void createOrUpdate(DataModel dataModel) {
    DataModel savedDataModel = dataModelRepository.save(dataModel);
}
```

When I try to save entity, in log I see many select queries:

```
Name:test-ds, Connection:9, Time:0, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["
    select
        outputfiel0_.model_id as model_id8_4_0_
    from
        data_model_output_field outputfiel0_ 
    where
        outputfiel0_.output_field_id=1"]


Name:test-ds, Connection:9, Time:0, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["
    select
        outputfiel0_.model_id as model_id8_4_0_
    from
        data_model_output_field outputfiel0_ 
    where
        outputfiel0_.output_field_id=2"]


Name:test-ds, Connection:9, Time:0, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["
    select
        outputfiel0_.model_id as model_id8_4_0_
    from
        data_model_output_field outputfiel0_ 
    where
        outputfiel0_.output_field_id=3"]


Name:test-ds, Connection:9, Time:0, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["
    select
        outputfiel0_.model_id as model_id8_4_0_
    from
        data_model_output_field outputfiel0_ 
    where
        outputfiel0_.output_field_id=4"]

Name:test-ds, Connection:9, Time:0, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["
    select
        outputfiel0_.model_id as model_id8_4_0_
    from
        data_model_output_field outputfiel0_ 
    where
        outputfiel0_.model_id=2"]
```

It takes each field by id. But why does he do, he can immediately pick up the list by `model_id`?

Moreover, at the very end of the log, he did it. Why did he need previous queries then?

**UPDATE**:

Simple example for reproduce: https://github.com/eaxdev/simple-web-app

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `save` method uses `EntityManager.merge` to flush the changes and you are using MERGE cascading. I don't know what kind of object graph you are trying to save here, but it seems that the `outputFields` collection has 4 entries which are first experiencing a MERGE cascade, i.e. Hibernate selects the current state for these objects, so that it can flush the changes. Next, Hibernate tries to flush the changes for the `DataModel#outputFields` relation i.e. the foreign keys, for which it needs to query all objects, so that it knows what to delete (which I think is required due to orphan removal).

It seems to me that `OutputField` and `IncrementField` have a compositional relationship with `DataModel`, so why not model them as `@Embeddable`? This way, Hibernate can manage the association in an more efficient manner.

Comment: Do you suggest that the ```OutputField``` and ```IncrementField``` entities annotate ```@Embeddable```? I tried to do this and it didn't have any effect. In the question I attached a link to the github of my example

Comment: If you use `@Embeddable` you also have to use `@ElementCollection` instead of `@OneToMany` and remove the ids from the `OutputField` and `IncrementField` classes. What do you mean it "didn't have any effect"?

Comment: I don't quite understand why I should delete primary keys in my tables? These are completely different tables and they are link through `OneToMany`

Comment: Because PKs are unnecessary/wrong when you use `@ElementCollection` and `@Embeddable`.